# Asignar valor a input

Tags: javascript, formularios, input, update, contentvalues

necesito de vuestra sabiduría, estoy desesperado, tengo un formulario en el cual he insertado un input y quiero asignarle el valor que obtengo de  `$(".id input").text(dataTable.row(this).data()[0]);`

Este es mi código html, la idea es hacer un update con la fecha que le inserto desde el input de fecha y que la id se rellene sola pero no hay forma de asignarle el valor de esa consulta javascript.

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>administracion/fechagasto_modificar"> 
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechanueva" name="fechanueva"   style="width: 85%;">

                     <div class="id">
                     <input id="id" name="id"/>
            
           
        </div>
                    
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn grey-mint btn-block" value="Añadir" />
                 
                 </div>
```

Comment: Buenas, de la siguiente forma no te funciona ?

$("#id").text(dataTable.row(this).data()[0]);

Answer (score 2):

Al ser un formulario con boton tipo submit, al hacer click en el boton recarga la pagina, o te redirege a otra y esto hace que no se pueda hacer lo que pides.
Para conseguir lo que quieres, en vez de actualizar el campo *id* al hacer click, se puede actualizar al cambiar el cambo *fechanueva*.

Te añado un ejemplo teniendo en cuenta tu codigo:

```js
$("#fechanueva").change(function() {
    $("#id").val($("#fechanueva").val());
});
```

```html
<!-- Este script solo es para que el ejemplo pueda ejecutar jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- A partir de aqui empieza el ejemplo -->

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>administracion/fechagasto_modificar"> 
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechanueva" name="fechanueva"   style="width: 85%;">
    <div class="id">
        <input id="id" name="id"/>           
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn grey-mint btn-block" value="Añadir" id="añadir"/>
</form>
```

Si por el contrario no vas a mandar nada del formulario a ningun lado, puedes conseguir lo que decias cambiando el type del boton a button y de esta forma no pasara lo descrito antes.

Te añado otro ejemplo:

```js
$("#añadir").click(function() {
    $("#id").val($("#fechanueva").val());
});
```

```html
<!-- Este script solo es para que el ejemplo pueda ejecutar jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- A partir de aqui empieza el ejemplo -->

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>administracion/fechagasto_modificar"> 
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechanueva" name="fechanueva"   style="width: 85%;">
    <div class="id">
        <input id="id" name="id"/>           
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="button" class="btn grey-mint btn-block" value="Añadir" id="añadir"/>
</form>
```